# Dropdown Form Links Not Working with Safari, but works on Edge and Chrome

Tags: html, forms, safari, dropdown

I'm having trouble with a dropdown form that redirects to a selected .pdf document.

You can visit https://accts.org/ethics.html to test it out for yourself. It works on Chrome and Edge, but not Safari. What do I need to do to get it to work on all browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: Please update the question with the code that needs debugging. Links can become obsolete over time.

Answer (score 0):

can we see the dropdown menu css? maybe there's a mistake in your code, and btw it's a bad idea to make dropdown menu with css only so this could be the reason why it works on some browsers only